# Deep JSON query with partial path in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, json

Given a number of JSON document like this:

```
  {
    id: some_id,
    l1: {
      f1: [
        {
          c1: foo,
          c2: bar
        },
        {
          c1: foo1,
          c2: bar1
        }
      ],
      f2: [
        {
          c3: baz,
          c4: bar
        }
      ]   
    }
  }
```

How can I query MySQL 5.7 for f1....c1: foo1 -- ie lX is not given nor is the list position of the c1-c2 subdocument.

This is not a duplicate of [Deep JSON query with partial path in PGSQL JSONB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444927/deep-json-query-with-partial-path-in-pgsql-jsonb) since that is about PostgreSQL and this one is about MySQL.

Comment: You ask for this??:: `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(T.your_field, '$.l1.f1[1].c1'), JSON_EXTRACT(T.your_field, '$.l1.f1[2].c2'), ....;` Full explited in [MySQL docs, 11.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(Doc, '$.*.f1[*].c1'), '"foo1"') FROM table;
```

If you're using 5.7.9 or later, you can replace the [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function with the [`->`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) operator:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(Doc->'$.*.f1[*].c1', '"foo1"') FROM table;
```